# Objective-C: Parsing a non-xml website

Tags: iphone, objective-c, html-parsing

I'd like to develop a very simple "bus timetable" app that loads a particular URL and can use the HTML to figure out bus numbers, their routes and expected times. Unfortunately it's a very simple website, so the data is spread across TD and DIV fields, rather than in xml.

Can anyone provide some pointers on where to start? I've had a look at NSURL, NSURLConnection and the like, and am able to download the contents of an HTML file, but I'm unsure what to do next.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways to accomplish this task.  Ultimately, you will want to retrieve something an easily-processed format other than *raw* html.  Here is one way to do it:

I would recommend writing a server-side script that converts the html into an easily-digestible format, such as JSON.

If you have php experience, you write a script / web-service  that grabs the needed elements and place the content in an associative array.   Place the script on your server and have your application call the web-service URL when ready to retrieve the info.

Finally, return the information as a JSON object and parse the JSON into your app.

```
<?php
    //parse html into the $array variable.
    $array = json_encode($array);
    echo $array;
?>
```

I would recommend using the SBJSON library for parsing the JSON object:  Take a look at [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Initiate your NSURL request by calling the script URL.

```
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoursite/script.php"]];
```

If the request is successful, parse the resulting JSON: (assuming use of SBJSON library)

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

NSError *error;
SBJSON *json = [[[SBJSON alloc] init]autorelease];
NSDictionary *busData = [json objectWithString:responseString error: &error];
//busData contains bus data that you formatted...
```

Beware, this is assuming that you want to add your data to a dictionary and then display it appropriately.  I consider this a mere snippet for formatting data in a way you desire.  Parsing all of the html within the app may difficult and that is why I advocate formatting the data as JSON first.  If you decide to go the XML route, there are several XML parsers as well.